# Open files from eclipse local terminal

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to open files from Eclipse' local terminal? i.e. ctrl + left click to open in a tab in eclipse?

[image]

Comment: Right-click and _Show In > Terminal_.

Comment: @howlger thanks, but I meant the other way around. To click on a file path+name in local terminal and open this file in Eclipse tab

Comment: I see. When the Eclipse executable file is on the path, `eclipse <file-to-open>` should work in the local terminal.

Comment: I will try that, thanks